# $_COOKIE is not available

Tags: php, jquery, post, cookies

I have written the PHP code to sign up users using jQuery's `$.post` method. I have the following scheme of files:

index.php (main page) > functions.php (regsistration form is located here, I use *include* to include my registration form in index.php) > jquery.js (to send $.post request to php.php) > php.php (all the php stuff is located here).

Now I want to set cookie in php.php upon successful registration. However, my cookie is not available in index.php.

What could make this problem happen ?

Comment: This is an overly vague question. Please provide some code, more details on the implementation, and/or a test URI.

Answer (score 0):

For cookies to be set, it requires a trigger.

*Registration:*

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){
  setCookie('Test'); // Testing cookie 
  }
```

Now, this is your example trigger, the changes will be appended and finalized after a refresh/redirect. which will then allow your cookie to be viewed.

This is all I can provide at this moment in time due to the content you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

I may have a prediction of what's happening, but some code would confirm it. A webserver first sends the headers (including "Content-Type: HTML", and "Expires: Someday"). "Set-Cookies" is one of those, and needs to be sent before any actual HTML content. If you try to set cookie values after you've already sent content, it will fail.

```
$_COOKIE['val1'] = 'This will theoretically get through.';
echo '<p>This is HTML!</p>';
$_COOKIE['value'] = 'And this will not get through.';
```

(I haven't done PHP specifically in a little while, so I actually may have forgetten whether `setcookie` is the required way of doing it)